# Is there a characterization of $C_c^*({R^n})$

Tags: functional-analysis

rt

Since we have already known a famous examples like $C_o^*({R^n})$, I think maybe there is a connection between them.

PS: ${C_c}({R^n})$ is defined as a LCS by the seminorms on the compact subsets(uniform norm)

Comment: Is something lost in your question? It doesn't look complete.

Comment: If you had looked up the famous example you know on Wikipedia you'd have [found this...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_linear_functionals_on_Cc.28X.29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I guess your meaning correctly, you are thinking of the Riesz representation theorem which says that $C_0^*(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space of continuous linear functionals on $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, is precisely the space of finite signed Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  You want to know what $C_c^*(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is.

It's the same.  Note that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a dense subspace of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  So if $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $C_0$, we can restrict it to $C_c$ and get another continuous linear functional.  Conversely, if $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $C_c$, then it has a unique continuous extension to the closure $C_0$ (standard fact).

Essentially, this is why, when discussing the dual space of a normed space $X$, there is no loss of generality in assuming $X$ is a Banach space: because we can replace $X$ by its completion, and $X^*$ doesn't change.

Edit: As mentioned by the comments, I'm assuming that you are equipping $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the uniform norm, but there are other possible topologies.  Could you clarify what you have in mind?

Comment: Well, sometimes $C_c(X)$ is given a certain non-Banach topology so that it will be complete.  For example, if $h$ is continuous but unbounded on $X$, then $f \mapsto \int fh$ is a linear funcional on $C_c(X)$, but does not correspond to a FINITE Radon measure.  Maybe our OP should tell us what he means?

Comment: Indeed, seconding @GEdgar's point, it matters considerably which topology we give $C_c(X)$: it can be an "LF-space" and be quasi-complete, although not metrizable. With the sup-norm, we get $C_o(X)$. With the seminorms from sups on compacts, we get Frechet $C(X)$. These are all reasonable in their own ways...

Comment: @GEdgar,@paul: Good points.  Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity of the topology on ${C_c}({R^n})$ ,if the topology is uniform topology, the answer is certainly right. But I really want to know is the situation when \[{C_c}({R^n})\] is defined as a LCS by the seminorms on the compact subsets(uniform norm).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.  Let $C_c(X)$ be the vector space of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact support.  Bourbaki defines a certain locally convex topology on this, making it a topological vector space.  I will let you look up that definition.  Then Bourbaki makes the DEFINITION: **An element of** $C_c(X)^*$ **is called a Radon measure**.  One of my fellow students in graduate school dubbed this *The Riesz Representation Definition*.